# Virtual Layers Clipping and Large Data Sets in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, virtual-layer

When working with large vector data sets in QGIS is there a method where you can ask QGIS to only load a small subset of your data?  I know that this can be done based on attributes using a virtual layer, but I am wondering if it is possible to do this for multiple large datasets and to get the same geographic coverage.  Sort of like clipping the same geographic slice out of multiple data sets, except that I don't want to clip my data.  Is this possible.  I am not sure that I have the language to describe it.

Comment: What type of data are you working with, ie. raster, vector, census, etc.?

Comment: I edited to be more specific.

Comment: are you currently using shapefiles? The limitations of that format are probably what you're experiencing. If possible, spin up a postgis server via virtualbox and load the same data in their... i'll be you'll find the performance you're after!

Comment: Yes, I am using shapefiles.  I am looking for a way to manage base data (provincial roads, freshwater atlas, forestry poly's etc.) that my small company uses for basic mapping.  Is a PostGIS server the right choice for managing ~30 base data layers that we update from various governments on a yearly basis?  Are there any resources that you can share for a beginner to GIS data management?

Comment: PostGIS is the spatial extension for PostgreSQL - Udemy has some courses that have been recommended to me: https://www.udemy.com/spatialsql/ and https://www.udemy.com/beginners-guide-to-postgresql/ come to mind. But in terms of the data management, volume, and workflow you have in mind, yes, absolutely postgis/postgresql, qgis, etc. would help you out greatly over using just shapefiles...